# Facebook login in Swift give back an error

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-login

I am trying put to my app a button for facebook login and I followed all phases for this.

It is showing for me the error.

```
2019-03-11 18:27:20.844262-0300 Interativa[4738:696825] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"
2019-03-11 18:27:20.844566-0300 Interativa[4738:696825] Falling back to storing access token in NSUserDefaults because of simulator bug
2019-03-11 18:27:20.846731-0300 Interativa[4738:696825] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"
Optional(Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.core Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey=Unknown error building URL.})
```

What is going on?

Comment: Add this in your info.plist: <array>
  <string>fbapi</string>
  <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
  <string>fbauth2</string>
  <string>fbshareextension</string>
 </array>

Comment: Thanks for your answer @SaurabhJain, I've adding this code in info.plist. I followed the steps on facebook page but don't wokr!